# Heroku NodeJS Help – Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

Need help on deploying a nodeJS app to Heroku please. I have my Procfile and Package.son file. This is what I am getting...

> remote: Building source: remote:
>   remote: -----> Fetching custom git
>   buildpack... done 
>   remote:
>   remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected 
>   remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the build pack 
>   remote:       to use for this application automatically. 
>   remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks 
>   remote:

The message doesn't make sense to me as it says fetching build pack done..what else am I missing? Any suggestions please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you've set a custom buildpack. It's usually best, with node, to just use the official buildpack:

```
heroku buildpack:unset
```

Once you set that and push, it won't say "fetching custom buildpack," but rather it will tell you that it detected a node.js app. If it doesn't detect a node.js app, that means that your app is missing its package.json file (lowercase).

Comment: Thanks! But I am getting:
 `buildpack:unset` is not a heroku command.

Comment: Okay, I have unset it now...but getting this error instead:

remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote:       to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks

Comment: That means that there are no files in the app you're trying to push that match node (or any other platform). So there's no server.js or package.json checked into your git repository.

Comment: Thanks – I have chosen to go with AWS. Much easier. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I fixed it by first removing the custom buildpack I had set using the command:

```
heroku buildpacks:remove my-buildpack
```

To see what buildpack you are using you can run the command `heroku buildpacks`.

I then ran the command `npm init` to create a package.json file, and committed the changes.

Then to use the official buildpack I ran the command:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
```

And I was good to go! The error went away. If you already have a package.json you may not need to worry about running `npm init`, but it worked for me. Heroku talks about this problem in depth here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys