# heroku, node, express generator (error: Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack ...)

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am new to node and ran across this problem while trying to push to Heroku. I used the express generator to generate the file structure and am unsure of the right way to set things up, any help is appreciated!

```
/MyAppRoot
   >MyAppDir
     - package.json
     - app.js
     - etc.
   >node_modules
   -.git
```

I followed one of the answers in [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105737/heroku-nodejs-help-push-rejected-no-cedar-supported-app-detected) and get the following error:

```
   > heroku buildpacks
    === damp-forest-32070 Buildpack URL
   > git push heroku master
    Counting objects: 580, done.
    Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (208/208), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (580/580), 1.63 MiB | 623.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 580 (delta 345), reused 564 (delta 337)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/nodejs
    remote: 
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to detect set buildpack heroku/nodejs
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by Heroku's support staff when I created a ticket:
All those files should be in the repository's root directory of the application, by the sounds of it, it's one level deeper. The buildpack will only pick up the package.json file located in the root directory, and not in any sub-directory.

I re-ran the express app_name command,  did a cd command into the directory, did an npm install and then git init, followed [Heroku's node getting started guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile) and it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set nodejs buildpack. try this

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
```

and the try again `$ git push heroku master`

for more information on how buildpacks works [click here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure)

Comment: thanks, I did that earlier, and when I ran it again I got the following message:  The buildpack heroku/nodejs is already set on your app.

Comment: try verifying your package.json. follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778552/heroku-deploy-failed-using-nodejs